# LEFT MID RIGHT Extract Text After a Specific Character in a String in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a Column where 3 rows of data are combined into a Single Line and divided by `.`

Here are some data Example

```
Schema1
Schema1
Schema1.mtc_so_additional_attr
Schema1.mtc_so_contact_marketing_ref
Schema1.mtc_so_lcd_service.sord_no_src
Schema1.mtc_so_vat_amount.sord_no_src
Schema2.mtc_so_message__ct.msg_type
Schema2.mtc_so_message__ct.so_msg_no
```

From this Data, I am trying to find the `Field` name when it is available else Nothing.

I am using this query but it is not working. Does anyone of you know what I am doing wrong here?

```
=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND(".";A2))
```

Expected Output

```
Key.                                        Schema      Table                    Field
Schema1                                     Schema1     
Schema1                                     Schema1
Schema1.mtc_so_additional_attr              Schema1     mtc_so_additional_attr 
Schema1.mtc_so_contact_marketing_ref        Schema1     mtc_so_lcd_service
Schema1.mtc_so_lcd_service.sord_no_src      Schema1     mtc_so_lcd_service.      sord_no_src 
Schema1.mtc_so_vat_amount.sord_no_src       Schema1     mtc_so_vat_amount.      sord_no_src 
Schema2.mtc_so_message__ct.msg_type         Schema2     mtc_so_message__ct    msg_type 
Schema2.mtc_so_message__ct.so_msg_no        Schema2     mtc_so_message__ct    so_msg_no
```

Comment: Many examples showing how to do this exist on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Field column is looking for the first ".", whereas it looks like you need it to look for the second ".".  One way to make it look for the second (that is compatible with all versions of Excel) is the following:

```
=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND(".";A2;FIND(".";A2)+1))
```

If you really want to parse your strings in the way that you showed and you have Excel 365, then you could make this formula which would create all three fields: schema, table and field:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<main><sub>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2;".";"</sub><sub>")& "</sub></main>";"//sub"))
```

This will create a dynamic array of 1 to 3 fields for each input (A2).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have **Excel 365** you can do it with some helper columns.

[image]

**Point count** (column C, orange area): `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSITUTE(A2,".",""))`.

**Positions**

- Column D: is a constant
- Column E (light green): `=IF(C2=0,LEN(A2),FIND(".",A2))`. Based on the number of points we take either "LEN" or "FIND".
- Column F (green): `=IF(C2<=1,LEN(A2),FIND(".",A2,E2+1))`.
- Column G (dark green): `=LEN(A2)`.

**Results** (columns I to K, blue area): `=SUBSTITUTE(MID($A2,D2,E2-D2),".","")`. In order to handle a position determined by "LEN" the same way as if it were determined by "FIND", we wrap it in another "SUBSTITUTE".